# What is the fastest (realistic) storage implementation to retrieve similar entries?

Tags: algorithm, distance

I read about [BK-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) (Burkhard-Keller-Trees) some months ago and it is said to be a good method for saving stuff that you want to read out again by **distance-metrics**. So in each case where you want to retrieve something by similarity.

However, these BK-trees **do not seem really fast** to me. When I tried an implementation and did some output, it had to travel around through the tree a lot as soon as I allowed longer distances (I trued it with levenshtein and allowed up to 6 edits).

The fastest implementation (if it’s only about speed) of course would be to store distances **from each to each entry** in a table and look them up directly, but this is too much overhead.

Thus I added *realistic* in the title. It is **okay to require some more memory**, but the implementation should still be realistic and usable (I do not know enough about such techniques to say what realistic is, but I guess there is some border).

Is there something faster than BK-trees available or is BK really the top of the mountain (yet)?

## Scenario

I do not have a real use-case, but scenario is as follows: I have like 1 mio entries of anything and they have some distance to each other (defined by a distance function). Now I get one entry and want to know either:

- which 5 entries do best match the given entry
- which other entries (independant of number) are lower or equal the same up to a given threshold

**Database** does not matter.

I guess in the end the best algorithm will match both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another tree-based nearest neighbour metric is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree. It claims to be practical, and http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ has picked it up, so it my indeed be so. However, nearest neighbour seems to be hard to do exactly, with trees, or with anything else, because there are a number of proposals floating around for approximate nearest neighbour, which I presume would be pretty silly if it wasn't hard. I can see one for edit distance at http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/edit.ps.

Another way to do approximate nearest neighbour search is to hope that the nearest neighbour will have a contiguous section of characters that occurs exactly in your query string. Then for all the strings in the database, chop them into all contiguous k-long substrings and build a table you can use with exact match. Then for your query string consider all k-long contiguous substrings, do an exact match for these, and compute the edit distance to all the strings from the database that you have found with this exact search for k-long substrings.